# Has Starfleet ever made First Contact with a pre-established space-faring species oblivious to alien intelligence?

Tags: star-trek

I've seen a fair majority of the material which comprises primary Star Trek canon.  I've watched all the TNG-era shows, *all* the movies (as far back as The Motion Picture), and am currently working through the Enterprise series.

Through all this time, I've seen Starfleet make First Contact with a wide variety of species in many different stages of development.  However, there's one particularly interesting scenario which I can't recall ever having seen happen.  It's possible this will happen in an episode I haven't seen yet (i.e.: Enterprise Season 2 or later, or any TOS/TAS episode) or I may have just forgotten it.

What I'm looking for is a situation where Starfleet has made First Contact with a race that meets both of the following criteria:

- Already has and has been using warp technology for quite some time - not just recently developed.
- Is, until encountering Starfleet personnel, oblivious to the existence of intelligent alien life forms.

Has this happened in Star Trek history?  If so, which episode?

Comment: As chock-full-O-races as the Star Trek galaxy seems to be, I doubt it would be possible to travel to more than a handful of other systems without tripping over another race.

Comment: @Xantec ...which is particularly what would really make this scenario *interesting*.

Comment: It's debatable, but I think the race from [Blink of an Eye](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Blink_of_an_Eye_(episode)) might come close.

Comment: @Xantec: Who knows, the fringe regions of the galaxy might be more sparsely populated.?

Comment: @Junuxx That only meets the second qualification - not the first.  When First Contact was initially made, the civilization was not just pre-warp - they were *pre-industrial*.  Even after First Contact, even if they *had* warp drive (which I don't recall being established), they still hadn't found a way out of their system yet.

Comment: Was there an episode of Voyager like this...?   Maybe I'm thinking Stargate, lol.

Comment: @Iszi: from Memory Alpha: `As Seven scans the surface she detects warp experimentation. Soon after, Voyager is being attacked by antimatter torpedoes and a tricobalt device.` And it's hard to define "quite some time" given the timey-wimey in this episode. Anyway it's the best fit I could think of.

Comment: @Junuxx Except that first contact was technically made with the race's Apollo era civilization (when they boarded Voyager). Unless you count the Doctor's visit, which was earlier.

Comment: @Junuxx Good point regarding the warp experimentation.  However, it still stands that First Contact (on several levels) happened well before the civilization developed warp technology.  The very first, of course, would be back when Voyager was mistaken for a new star in the sky.  Then, the Doctor had his three-year excursion to the surface.  Finally, two members of their pre-warp space program boarded Voyager.

Comment: Undercover missions on prewarp planets are normally not considered first contact AFAIK. You could argue that "official" first contact is when communications are established with the authorities, which would be after Gotana-Retz (the astronaut) returns home and warp tech is developed. But I definitely see your point, which is why I made this a comment starting with "It's debatable, but..." instead of an answer.

Comment: It has happened but I don't remember the specifics. You guys are killing me. It's like a job here. I haven't gotten out of the Fortress of Geekitude in weeks. Off to see if I can suss out the episode in question...

Comment: @Thaddeus: I agree; There *was* one incident where "they" met a warp capable civilisation who didn't have contact with any other life forms. But I too cannot remember which series/episode that was. I'm guessing TNG or ENT, though.

Comment: @Junuxx why would a race with no extensive space program (and thus possibly space wars among themselves) AND no prior contact with hostile ETs have developed weapons whose sole purpose is attacking spaceships? Tells me they did have prior contact, and it wasn't a happy experience for them.

Comment: @Junuxx earth itself is at the outer edge of the galaxy...

Comment: @jwenting: Seems we too have a different interpretation of 'contact'. See my other comments here. Also, I'm not sure what you mean to say with your second comment.

Comment: @Junuxx you said maybe on the fringes of the galaxy such a civilisation might exist. Earth is on the fringes (in fact there's a school of thought that nearer the center life probably can't evolve because of the environment there).

Comment: @jwenting: Yes I'm familiar with that theory. But I was really thinking of the outermost fringe where stars are very isolated. Sol is at ~27kly from the galactic center. With the galaxy's radius being about 50kly, we are more halfway than at the outer edge.

Comment: @jwenting Earth is actually located ~2/3 of the galactic radius away from the center.

Comment: there is that race of lizard people whom kirk fought one of once.  There's no proof that they weren't oblivious

Comment: “I... am currently working through the Enterprise series.” You have my sympathies.

Comment: @SamIam The Gorn Hegemony existed for longer than the Federation (the name of their government was mentioned in ENT), and was known to have contact with other systems prior to their first contact with humans in TOS

Answer (score 17):

There is one that *might* qualify.  The photonic lifeforms from VOY 5x12, [Bride of Chaotica!](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Bride_of_Chaotica!_(episode)) believed that all biochemical lifeforms were artificial, while photonic lifeforms - such as the Doctor - were living.

So they've never before made first contact with what we'd consider a species, but it implies that they have previously made first contact with other living photonic lifeforms.

They're also trans-dimensional, so "spacefaring" isn't quite the right descriptor...  But, their humanoid form may perhaps look familiar:

[image: Photonic life-form]

Comment: It's a fudge but you're technically correct, the best kind of correct...

Answer (score 10):

Enterprise (TNG) makes first contact with a Tamarian ship at the planet El-Adrel, in the 'Darmok' episode. The Tamarians had been transmitting signals toward Federation space for weeks so were probably aware of 'alien intelligence' for at least that length of time. There is no mention of them being aware of aliens or a part of an aliance prior to this encounter.

Their ship though, was roughly equal in armament and technology to the Enterprise. Maybe even a bit tougher. Tamarian captain Dathon and Captain Picard become friends during the encounter and though Dathan is ultimately killed, both sides see this first contact as a good start. Dathan records in his log, "Picard and Dathon at El-Adrel", which Picard gives this to Dathan's First Officer who then withdraws back to Tamarian space. It does seem that is was actually 'they' who initiated first contact or at least invited it. A tentative first attempt at contacting aliens?

Per Memory Alpha: "Picard and Dathon at El-Adrel" means, a "Successful first contact between two alien cultures, or to work toward a common goal", in the Tamarian language.

Comment: I don't understand the 'down vote' with no explanation given and no comment. This answer is admittedly mixed with some speculation but no more so than the other two potential answers to a nearly unanswerable question. I see no down voted there... Down votes should be explained.

Comment: @Morgan I didn't downvote but I agree they should be explained and I think I can guess why someone would. Read the q again. OP is looking for an encounter with a species "Oblivious to alien intelligence". Now re-watch the first minutes of the episode. It is mentioned that "The children of Tamah" were encountered in the past and that communication wasn't succesfully achieved. It is also thought that they were trying at the time to communicate with the Federation.

Comment: The Tamarians had been aware of the Federation before hand: `DATA: Federation vessels have encountered Tamarian ships seven times over the past one hundred years.`

Comment: @Xantec I hear what you're saying. I'm not trying to split hairs but the prior contacts doesn't preclude satisfaction of the 2nd half of the OP. They obviously satisfy the 1st half "•Already has and has been using warp technology for quite some time - not just recently developed." As for the second half "•Is, until encountering Starfleet personnel, oblivious to the existence of intelligent alien life forms." There's no indication the Tamarians were associated with or aware of other species before contact with Starfleet. Even their ship was manned by only 1 species as far as we could tell.

Comment: True enough, I suppose. Although considering how crowded the Alpha quadrant is they would have to be extremely insular to not have run into anyone else. Although the very first encounter between Starfleet and the Tamarians may have been their first contact, but no way to know.

Comment: @Morgan The contacts were sufficient for Starfleet to have been completely frustrated in attempts to actually communicate with them--the signals being sent were basically an invitation to help advance that issue along.  And the Tamarians are hardly distinct in having single-species crews.  I don't think we ever see a ship manned by more than one species that aren't Federation ships until the Dominion--assuming you count the occasional Weyoun or Founder.

Answer (score 5):

I might be wrong, as it is very hard to prove a negative. That said, **NO** the situation you describe has never come to pass. The closest I can find was The Probe from Star Trek IV which was from an intelligent race that had warp tech for a long time, but they knew intelligent life existed outside themselves. They just didn't know that it could exist in humanoid from before meeting the Federation.

As the current ST universe stands, such a race would be impossible since the Federation is surrounded on all sides by intelligent races that would be the first contact of a race that had warp for any significant time. The only shows that could have encountered such a thing were *The Original Series*, *Enterprise*, or *Voyager* and I can find no mention of anything like that when looking through the episode summaries (I also watched most the episodes as well, but we all know how fallible human memory can be).

The odds are similarly slim when you look inside the Federations borders. This space is supposedly searched fairly thoroughly, with Federation scientists watching races that are moving toward First Contact. I suppose a race that lived out of sync with the rest of the universe could exist, but it definitely hasn't been explored in any of the TV shows.

Anyway, if it turns out I'm wrong I will delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a *long* time since I saw the movie, so this is more guessing than verified information, but V-ger explored entire galaxies before returning home, so it seems unlikely that it didn't manage to find a culture fitting your description. Since V-ger was launched in *our* past, it wasn't part of the Federation at the time. However, we could retro-actively claim it, since Starfleet essentially absorbs NASA between now and then.

That said, it seems unlikely that many warp-capable species would be unaware of alien life in this region of the galaxy. As said in other answers, there are a lot of life forms in the Star Trek universe (about 355 species in the Alpha and Beta quadrants that have pages on [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Alpha_and_Beta_Quadrant_species)). 
In addition to that though, notice that even Earth didn't get the chance to develop our warp program alone. After *one flight*, the Vulcans came to <s>ride herd and control our space program</s> say "Hello".